# Create a grid with UIImageview

Tags: ios

I built a photo library that show image in my app folder, then I want to make it look like the Homescreen. When I tap and hold any image, all images will shake and have a delete button on the top right corner like icons on Homescreen.

Anyone know any sample code, tutorial or how to do that?

I used scrollview to make photolibrary

I built a photo library that show image in my app folder, then I want to make it look like the Homescreen. When I tap and hold any image, all images will shake and have a delete button on the top right corner like icons on Homescreen.

Anyone know any sample code, tutorial or how to do that?

I used scrollview to make photolibrary

/---------------------Solution for my question-----------------/
Thanks @Vizllx

With Vizllx answer I solved this.

I used GMGridView to create photo library with edit mode. It's perfect but if I load a large number of images the gridview will slow lag when scrolling fast. To solve this I use

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create();

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateMyUIWithResult:result];
    });    
});
```

That's it. I edited my question for who has same problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMGridView will help you for sure,
**Check out the link** 
https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView

Comment: Is this legal on appstore

Comment: absolutely.... mate... already used and approved in appstore

Comment: accept the answer mate so that it can be helpful for other users too.

Comment: I had checked and applied it in my project after modified some codes.
I work well. But another problem was found that when I load many photos it slow down when scroll. any solution?

Comment: I'm about to switch to UICollectionView but it has some problem on iOS7

Answer (score 0):

You may implemet using CABasicAnimation for animating icons like in springboard.. refer this link http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uicollectionview-layouts/